# Integral of positive part of harmonic function over circles goes to infinity

Tags: complex-analysis, functional-analysis, harmonic-functions

I have been thinking about this problem off and on for a couple days now to no avail.

**If in answering this question you could address the things I've tried so far as "on the right track", "not really a good idea", etc, I would be very grateful.**

> Let $u: \mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{R}$ be a harmonic function on the entire complex plane, and let $u_+$ be the positive part, that is, $u_+(z) = \max(u(z), 0)$. Let 
>   $$T(r) = \int_{0}^{2\pi} u_+(re^{i\theta}) d\theta$$
>   Show that $T(r) \to \infty$ as $r\to \infty$.

It's so bothersome to me because it seems like an elementary and intuitive result.

My first thought, purely based on mental pictures I have of harmonic functions, was that a harmonic function with $u(0) = 0$ (the problem can be reduced to this) has some sort of radial monotonicity or even convexity, ie, that $r\mapsto u(re^{i\theta})$ is convex for $r \in [0,1]$. This would surely give the result; the only problem is that it's very false.

My other idea was as follows: if $R> r$, let $A = \{\theta \in [0, 2\pi): u(re^{i\theta}) > 0\}$. If we can get some constant $C_{R/r}>1$ which satisfies
$$\int_{\theta \in A} u(re^{i\theta}) d\theta \leq C_{R/r} \int_{\theta \in A} u(Re^{i\theta}) d\theta$$
then we'll be done, since
$$T(r) \leq C_{R/r} \int_{\theta \in A} u(Re^{i\theta}) d\theta \leq C_{R/r}T(R)$$

The obvious thing to try to make some estimate like this work is to represent $u(re^{i\theta}) = P_{r/R} * u(Re^{i\theta})$, where $P_q$ is the Poisson kernel. But I have not been able to make this work.

I don't think this problem should be this hard, so please point me in the right direction. Thanks!

Comment: I think the trick is that the pointwise maximum of two [subharmonic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subharmonic_function) functions is subharmonic.

Comment: That’s true. I’ll try to think about that

Comment: $z \mapsto \max(0,u(z))$ and $z \mapsto w(z)=  \int_{0}^{2\pi} \max(0,u(ze^{i\theta})) d\theta$ are subharmonic and non-constant [thus (th.8) they are unbounded](http://www.dm.unibo.it/~arcozzi/subharmonic.pdf).